# Get Value Inside Div with an ID with PHP or jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am making an page that will automatically display the number of subscribers for a Youtube user on a PHP page.

On the Youtuber's homepage, there is a DIV with an id of 'profile_show_subscriber_count'.

I would like to use PHP or even jQuery (I know they're totally separate, but I think it is possible with both) to get the value between the  and the < div > and the < / div > (a number).

Anyone know how to do this?
PS - I could also do this for total views with the same method.

Comment: Instead of scraping, why dont you check if there's an API available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the API
http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html

http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

There's always `$('#profile_show_subscriber_count').text()`. But yeah, TJHeuvel above is correct. You should use an API if one is available.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
$("#profile_show_subscriber_count").get();
```

It may give you more than you need...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following functions

`$("#the_div").get();`

`$("#the_div").html();`

`$("#the_div").text();`

Comment: The problem with this is that it assumes that <div id="the_div"> is on the same page as my code. Which it isn't.